# Checking master checkbox after putting text to slave textarea and checkboxing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got problem with my checkboxes. Currently I automatically check the master checkbox after  the slave is `checked`. The slave is automatically `checked` after typing in the textarea, however I'm not able to make the master checkbox `checked` after typing in the textarea.

I would like to check the slave checkbox and the master checkbox after putting text in the textarea.

Here is my current code:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="master" value="1" id="wod">master<BR>
--<input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="slave" value="1" id="sth">
<input type='text' name='tekst'  size=1 maxlength=3 onkeyup="userTyped('sth', this)">
```

JS:

```
function userTyped(name_chbox, e){
    if(e.value.length > 0){
        document.getElementById(name_chbox).checked=true;
     }else{
        document.getElementById(name_chbox).checked=false;
    }

 }

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slave").click(function () {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            $(".master").attr('checked', this.checked);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bb92N/2/

Comment: Couldn't you write it ch**e**kbox ?

Comment: Sorry for that - it was my mistake, I will correct myself next time.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="master" value="1" id="wod">master<BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="slave" value="1" id="sth">
<input type='text' name='tekst' class="tekst"  size=1 maxlength=3>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slave").click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".master").prop('checked', this.checked);
        }
    });

    $('.tekst').keyup(function(){
        $('.master, .slave').prop('checked', this.value.length > 0);
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7tMNP/)

Comment: Thanks ,I have changed my jquery libraries and your script is working excellent. Now I'm trying to make the checkbox stayed checked - even when I will delete the text in text area.

Comment: @user2463248 Change `$('.master, .slave').prop('checked', this.value.length > 0);` to `$('.master, .slave').prop('checked', true);`